# How can I search for one word within a MySQL TEXT data type?

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I have a TEXT field called 'camps' inside my 'customers' table which can hold multiple words. 
Each user can have zero to about 50 words inside the field (separated by spaces.)

I'm trying to search through each 'camps' field of each row to determine which user has a certain word inside their 'camps' field.

Example:

User 1 has: 'Camp1 Camp2 Camp3 Camp7' in their 'camps' field.

User 2 has: 'Camp2' in their 'camps' field.

User 3 has: '' in there 'camps' field.

Let's say I search for all people with Camp2, I want it determine User1 and User2 have Camp2 in their 'camps' field.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$camp = $_POST['camp'];

$customers = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE camps LIKE '%$camp'";

$result = mysql_query($customers);
```

At the moment it seems to only be detecting exact values inside the 'camps' field. If I pass it "Camp2", only User 2 will show. I would like for User 1 and User 2 to show. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string`, Use it!!!!

Comment: You seem to be associating each user with multiple camps. The right way to do that would be a separate table with columns for user id and camp, not a text column.

Comment: Use `MATCH() AGAINST()` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match. Also, think of what @bfavaretto said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing your other wildcard.  Remember, you need to match things that have other text AFTER your search term, too.  User2 was being found because "Camp2" is the *last* item in the camps field.

```
$customers = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE camps LIKE '%$camp%'";
```

... or if you want to make it a little easier to read:

```
$customers = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE camps LIKE '%" . $camp. "%'";
```

... or perhaps even:

```
$sqlfmt = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE camps LIKE '%%%s%%'";
...
$customers = sprintf($sqlfmt, $camp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another wildcard in the end of the string to note that you're searching for anything having "camp", like:

```
$customers = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE camps LIKE '%mysql_real_escape_string($camp)%'";
```

Or, if you want to do something more complex, you could use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp). (untested)

```
$customers = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE camps REGEXP '^(mysql_real_escape_string($camp))$";
```

Read the MySql documentation on [pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) for more information

*obs*: notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string like [Okonomiyaki3000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275019/okonomiyaki3000) said.

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause should be:

```
where camps like '%Camp2%'
```

You can replace `Camp2` with your variable by concatenation.